# Parsing via SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column that gives info on how to parse another column within the same table.The column has the property name and string length of the value that it appears in the next column. Here is how it looks:

```
PropertyNames   PropertyValuesString
SP_PartnerCode:S:0:14:FirstName:S:14:5:LastName:S:19:9: InvestProBase2rogerpatterson
SP_PartnerCode:S:0:14:FirstName:S:14:5:LastName:S:19:7: InvestProBase2AaronSchmidt
SP_PartnerCode:S:0:0:FirstName:S:0:6:LastName:S:6:9:    JosephGaultieri
SP_PartnerCode:S:0:14:FirstName:S:14:4:LastName:S:18:9: InvestProBase2ToddEdmondson
SP_PartnerCode:S:0:14:FirstName:S:14:7:LastName:S:21:4: InvestProBase2MichaelLove
```

I want to separate this into a column per property name, like this:

```
SP_PartnerCode  FirstName   LastName
InvestProBase2  roger   patterson
InvestProBase2  Aaron   Schmidt
    Joseph  Gaultieri
InvestProBase1  Kevin   Lemmon
InvestProBase1  John    Switzer
InvestProBase2  bryan   abbott
InvestProBase2  Todd    Edmondson
InvestProBase2  Michael Love
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This needs a redesign. You will never be able to effectively query this mess. Go back and read about normalization and stop using a design like this. Rule one, never store more than one piece of information in a field. You broke rule 1 of database design. Not only will this be horrible to build queries for but it will be a performance hog. This is a system that should never be allowed to go to production. If you are asking this to parse the info from another sytem to put in your correclty normalized design, ignore my rant.

Comment: I assume this is external data? Have you considered using SSIS to transform the data to fit into your schema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should really normalize your data, was the first thing that came to my mind.

This function parses your data for a given property:

```
create function Parse(@property nvarchar(4000), 
    @meta nvarchar(4000), @data nvarchar(4000))
returns nvarchar(4000)
as
begin
    set @meta = N':' + @meta

    declare @iproperty int, @itype int, @ibegin int, @ilength int, @iend int
    set @iproperty = charindex(N':' + @property + N':', @meta)
    if @iproperty = 0 return null

    set @itype = charindex(N':', @meta, @iproperty + 1)
    set @ibegin = charindex(N':', @meta, @itype + 1)
    set @ilength = charindex(N':', @meta, @ibegin + 1)
    set @iend = charindex(N':', @meta, @ilength + 1)

    declare @sbegin nvarchar(5), @slength nvarchar(5)
    set @sbegin = substring(@meta, @ibegin + 1, @ilength - @ibegin - 1)
    set @slength = substring(@meta, @ilength + 1, @iend - @ilength - 1)

    declare @begin int, @length int
    set @begin = convert(int, @sbegin)
    set @length = convert(int, @slength)

    if @length = 0 return null

    return substring(@data, @begin + 1, @length)
end
```

and then SELECT your data

```
select 
dbo.Parse('SP_PartnerCode', PropertyNames, PropertyValuesString) as SP_PartnerCode,
dbo.Parse('FirstName', PropertyNames, PropertyValuesString) as FirstName,
dbo.Parse('LastName', PropertyNames, PropertyValuesString) as LastName
from MyTable
```

Comment: Wow devio, that worked flawlessly!! Now I can get to normalizing this mess. Thx!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

Comment: substring would certainly work, but you may want to consider doing the split in your application or presentation layers.  SQL is notoriously weak in string manipulation.